# Return cleaner Simple HTML DOM array

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

Im using Simple HTML Dom to return an array from a table on a page, the table is like this

```
<table width="414" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="170">Total :</td>
<td>58,262</td>
</tr>
... // there are about another 10 <tr> tags, and table closing tags after that.
```

But when i run the command `print_r($es = $html->find('table[width=414]'));` i get returned a huge array (in contrast to what its parsing) the below example takes us up to the first 'Total :' line, the next  is about 200 lines below. Any ideas how i can get a more 'sanitized' result back ?

```
Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => table [attr] => Array ( [cellpadding] => 0 [cellspacing] => 4 [border] => 0 [width] => 414 ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => tr [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => td [attr] => Array ( [width] => 170 ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 3 [tag] => text [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( ) [nodes] => Array ( ) [parent] => simple_html_dom_node Object *RECURSION* [_] => Array ( [4] => Total : )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the pre tags :

```
<pre>

    <?php print_r($es = $html->find('table[width=414]'); ?>

</pre>
```

What this does is generate the correct HTML for spaces and line feeds from the result of print_r.